# Calculating the root of an almost polynomial expression.

Tags: real-analysis, polynomials, roots, exponentiation

Recently I ran across the problem of trying to solve the following equation, where $\varepsilon \in (0,1)$ and $x \geq 0$:

$$ x^{1+\varepsilon} - x - 2\pi = 0. \tag{eq}$$

Luckily, for me it suffices to know that the unique zero of this equation is between $1$ and $2\sqrt[\varepsilon]{2}$ when $\varepsilon < \frac 1 2
$, but I am now curious; **are there methods of solving the exact roots of such "almost polynomials"?**

**EDIT:** As a closing comment, in case I or someone else needs to approximate the solution in the future, here's an ad hoc argument to show that for any $\beta\in(0,1)$ there exists $\varepsilon_0>0$ such that for all $\varepsilon < \varepsilon_0$ the unique positive root of equation (eq) is between $\varepsilon^{-\beta}$ and $\varepsilon^{-1}$.

Denote 
  \begin{align*}
    h(x) 
    = x^{1+\varepsilon} - x 
    = x(x^\varepsilon - 1), 
  \end{align*}
  whence $h([0,1]) \subset [-2,0]$,  $h(1) = 0$, $h'(x) = (1+\varepsilon)x^\varepsilon -1 > 0$ for all $x > 1$ 
  and $h''(x) > 0$ for all $x > 0$. Thus we know that in the interval $[1,\infty)$ there is a unique solution, denoted $S(\varepsilon)$,
  to the equation (eq) with $S(\varepsilon) > S(\varepsilon')$, when $\varepsilon < \varepsilon'$.

To estimate $S(\varepsilon)$ in terms of $\varepsilon$
  observe that for any $\beta \in (0,1)$ we have
  \begin{align*}
    h( \varepsilon^{-\beta} )
    = \varepsilon^{-\beta} \left(\varepsilon^{-\beta \varepsilon} - 1\right)
    =\frac{\varepsilon^{-\beta \varepsilon} - 1}{\varepsilon^\beta},
  \end{align*}
  and by using l'Hopital's rule we see that
  \begin{align*}
    \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{x^{-\beta x}-1}{x^\beta}
%    &=\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{D (x^{-\beta x}-1)}{D x^\beta}
    &=\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{D (e^{-\beta x \log(x)}-1)}{\beta x^{\beta-1}} \\
    &=\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{-x^{-\beta x} \beta (\log(x)+1)}{\beta x^{\beta-1}} \\
    &=\lim_{x \to 0} -\underbrace{\left( x^x \right)^{-\beta}}_{\to 1} \underbrace{x^{1-\beta} (\log(x)-1)}_{\to 0}
      = 0.
  \end{align*}
  This means that for any $\beta < 1$ and all $\varepsilon > 0$ 
  small enough, $h(\varepsilon^{-\beta}) \leq 2\pi$ and thus
  $S(\varepsilon)  \leq \varepsilon^{-\beta}$.
  Similarly, by repeating the calculations above with $\beta = 1$
  we see that
  \begin{align*}
    \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{x^{- x}-1}{x}
    &=\lim_{x \to 0} -\underbrace{\left( x^x \right)^{-1}}_{\to 1} \underbrace{(\log(x)-1)}_{\to -\infty}
      = \infty 
      > 2\pi.
  \end{align*}
  Thus $S(\varepsilon) \geq \varepsilon^{-1}$ for $\varepsilon > 0$ small enough.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nope. Even if we know $\varepsilon$ to be a fraction, $\varepsilon=\tfrac ab$, we see the equation $x^{1+\varepsilon}-x-c=0$ reduces to

$$x^{a+b}=(x+c)^b$$

which we can't (always) solve, as we can only consistently solve $4$th-or-less degree polynomials exactly.

Comment: Oh, that's clever! I was guessing that the anwer would likely be 'no', but this is a nice way of seeing a major obstruction. (Unless polynomial equations of the type $x^{a+b} = (x+c)^b$ are unusual in their solvability, which I kinda doubt.)

Answer (score 0):

For equations like $$x^{1+\varepsilon} - x - 2\pi = 0.$$

Our algebra at this point is not sufficient to solve for an exact solution.

Fortunately, numerical methods such as Newton's Method provide very good approximations to the solution.

Comment: Not only "at this point"; it's been proven that there cannot be an exact formula for such equations.